# Using indexes when comparing datetimes

Tags: sql-server, datetime, indexing, casting, sql-server-2016

I have two tables, both of which containing millions of rows of data.

```
tbl_one:
purchasedtm DATETIME,
userid      INT,
totalcost   INT

tbl_two:
id          BIGINT,
eventdtm    DATETIME,
anothercol  INT
```

The first table has a clustered index on the first two columns: `CLUSTERED INDEX tbl_one_idx ON(purchasedtm, userid)`

The second one has a primary key on its ID column, and also a non-clustered index on the `eventdtm` column.

I want to run a query which looks for rows in which `purchasedtm` and `eventdtm` are on the same day.

Originally, I wrote my query as:

```
WHERE CAST(tbl_one.purchasedtm AS DATE) = CAST(tbl_two.eventdtm AS DATE)
```

But this was not going to use either of the two indexes.

Later, I changed my query to this:

```
WHERE tbl_one.purchasedtm >= CAST(tbl_two.eventdtm AS DATE)
AND tbl_one.purchasedtm < DATEADD(DAY, 1, CAST(tbl_two.eventdtm AS DATE))
```

This way, because only one side of the comparison is wrapped in a function, the other side can still use its index. Correct?

I also have some additional questions:

- I can write the query the other way around too, i.e. keeping `tbl_two.eventdtm` untouched and wrapping `tbl_one.purchasedtm` in `CAST()`. Would that make a difference in performance?
- If the answer to the previous question is yes is it because `eventdtm` has its own dedicated index, while looking up `purcahsedtm` would only be a partial index match?
- Are there other factors I can take into consideration for deciding which of the two choices is better? (For example, if there are millions of rows in `tbl_one` but billions of rows in `tbl_two`, would that impact which column I should CAST and which one I should not?)
- In genera, if you compare two columns that are both indexed, would we gain any performance compared to a similar scenario in which only one of them is indexed?
- And lastly, can I perform my original task without using CAST?

Note: I do not have the ability to create or modify indexes, add columns, etc.

Comment: `WHERE CAST(tbl_one.purchasedtm AS DATE) = CAST(tbl_two.eventdtm AS DATE)` *"But this was not going to use either of the two indexes."* Wrong. `CAST([column] AS date)` ***is*** SARGable/ [SARGable functions in SQL Server](http://blogs.lobsterpot.com.au/2010/01/22/sargable-functions-in-sql-server/)

Comment: Ideally the userid      would be a PK for table 1 and you'd have another table with all of the purchases. Are you joining these on the IT fields? If so, swapping the order of that clustered key would help.

Comment: Is your revised query using the index?

Comment: @Larnu I did not know that! Very interesting. I will read more and update my question. But can you respond to it in a non-SARGable context? (e.g. if I was using a CAST that was not SRGable, or a function other than CAST)

Comment: *Most* of the time applying **any** function to a Column in your `WHERE` will make it non-SARGable. The only one I can think of is actually SARGable is`CAST({column},AS date)`. I don't remember for sure off the top of my head, but I think `CONVERT(int,DecimalColumn)` is SARGable. The most common thing you (I) see are things like `WHERE ISNULL(MyColumn,0) = ISNULL(@MyVariable,0)` which isn't SARGable. Something like that would be better written using Boolean logic `WHERE (MyColumn = @MyVariable OR (MyColumn IS NULL AND @MyVariable IS NULL))`.

Comment: Note, however that applying a function to a variable, or literal expression is fine. So `WHERE GETDATE() >= CONVERT(date,MyDateColumn) AND GETDATE() < DATEADD(DAY, 1, CONVERT(date,MyDateColumn))` is "bad", due to the `DATEADD`, however, `WHERE MyDateColumn >= CONVERT(date,GETDATE()) AND MyDateColumn < DATEADD(DAY, 1, CONVERT(date,GETDATE())` is fine, as the `DATEADD` is applied to `GETDATE()`.

Comment: @Larnu, can you please post that as an answer? I would like to mark it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Little. late after commenting but...

As discussed in the comments, code such as `CAST(DateTimeColumn AS date)` is actually SARGable. Rob Farley posted an article on some of the SARGable and non-SARGable functionality [here](http://blogs.lobsterpot.com.au/2010/01/22/sargable-functions-in-sql-server/), however, I'll cover a few things off anyway.

Firstly, applying a function to a column will normally make your query non-SARGable, and especially if it changes the order of the values or the order of them is meaningless. Take something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE RIGHT(COLUMN,5) = 'value';
```

The order of the values in the column are utterly unhelpful here, as we're focusing on the right hand characters. Unfortunately, as Rob also discusses:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE LEFT(COLUMN,5) = 'value';
```

This is also non-SARGable. However what about the following?

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE Column LIKE 'value%';
```

This is, as the logic isn't applied to the column and the order doesn't change. If the value wehre `'%value%'` then that too would be non-SARGable.

When applying logic that adds (or subtracts) what you want to find, you always want to apply that to the literal value (or function, like GETDATE()`). For example one of these expressions is SARGable the other is not:

```
Column + 1  = @Variable --non-SARGable
Column = @Variable - 1 --SARGable
```

The same applies to things like `DATEADD`

```
@DateVariable BETWEEN DateColumn AND DATEADD(DAY, 30,DateColumn) --non-SARGable
DateColumn BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -30, @DateVariable) AND @DateVariable --SARGable
```

Changing the datatype (other than to a `date`) rarely will keep a query SARGable. `CONVERT(date,varchardate,112)` will not be SARGable, even though the order of the column is unchanged. Converting an `decimal` to an `int`, however, had the same result as converting a `datetime` to a `date`, and kept SARGability:

```
CREATE TABLE testtab (n decimal(2,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED);
INSERT INTO testtab
VALUES(0.1),
      (0.3),
      (1.1),
      (1.7),
      (2.4);
GO

SELECT n
FROM testtab
WHERE CONVERT(int,n) = 2;
GO    

DROP TABLE testtab;
```

[image]

Hopefully, that gives you enough to go on, but pelase do ask if you want me to add anything further.